# Creating an array of arrays and then retrieving the values

Tags: arrays, perl

I have input the following code:

```
my @resultsArray;
my @dataArray;
while (my ($id, $originLat, $originLng, $compensation ) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    @dataArray = ($id, $originLat, $originLng, $compensation);
    print "ID: $id Lat: $originLat Lng: $originLng Compensation: $compensation\n";
    print "Data Array: @dataArray\n";
    #the above code words.
    #I declare 
    push (@resultsArray, @dataArray);
}

my (@r1, @r2, @r3, @r4);
#issue here
for  (@resultsArray) {
    @r1 = pop(@resultsArray);
    @r2 = pop(@resultsArray);
    @r3 = pop(@resultsArray);
    @r4 = pop(@resultsArray);               

    print "ID: $r4[0] Lat: $r3[0] Lng: $r2[0] Compensation: $r1[0]\n";
    #@r1 = ();
}
```

The above code works.  The array `@dataArray` is pushed onto the `@resultsArray` stack and is popped into the `@r1, @r2, @r3, @r4` respectively.  However this is terrible code.  Is there a better way, a cleaner way with less lines that is still readable and that is generally more professional?

I'm looking to improve my skills.  I feel like I might be the laughing stock of a room if I show up with something like this.

Comment: Why do you use arrays for each of `@r1`, `@r2`, `@r3`, `@r4`? You seem to be using them as scalars. splice() is your friend. To take last 4 elements off the array, you can use: `@r` = splice @resultsArray, -4. Then you can utilize $r[0] .. $r[3].

Comment: That's really slick Steven.  Thanks. Shaved a lot off my code and made it look better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to learn how to use references.  Here's your code rewritten with array references:

```
my @resultsArray;
while (my ($id, $originLat, $originLng, $compensation ) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    my $dataArray = [$id, $originLat, $originLng, $compensation];
    print "ID: $id Lat: $originLat Lng: $originLng Compensation: $compensation\n";
    print "Data Array: @$dataArray\n";
    #the above code words.
    #I declare 
    push @resultsArray, $dataArray;
}

for my $r (@resultsArray) {
    print "ID: $r->[0] Lat: $r->[1] Lng: $r->[2] Compensation: $r->[3]\n";
}
```

Arrays of arrays in Perl are best represented as arrays of *array references*.

The magic here is

```
my $dataArray = [$id, $originLat, $originLng, $compensation];
```

This creates an anonymous array containing the four values, and then sets the *scalar* `$dataArray` to point to the anonymous array. This *reference* then gets pushed onto `@resultsArray`.  `@resultsArray` is now an array of scalars that happen to be references to other arrays. Those references can be *de-referenced* using the `->[n]` construct to get individual members of the array.